# How to query mongoDB to see if matching record exists, and if it does return it to update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Seems like a super basic task, but I just cannot get this to work (not very experienced with mongo or nodeJS).

I have an array of records.  I need to check the DB to see if any records with a matching name already exist and if they do grab that record so I can update it.

Right now I am trying this

```
function hit_the_db(db, record_name, site_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var record = db.collection('' + site_id + '_campaigns').find({name: record_name}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('...error => ' + err.message);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log('...promise resolved...');
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
    console.log('...second layer of select successful, returning data for ' + record.length + ' records...');

    return record;
  });
}
```

This query works in another part of the app so I tried to just copy it over, but I am not getting any records returned even though I know there should be with the data I am sending over.

`site_id` is just a string that would look like `ksdlfnsdlfu893hdsvSFJSDgfsdk`.  The `record_name` is also just a string that could really be anything but it is previously filtered so no spaces or special characters, most are something along these lines `this-is-the-name`.

With the names coming through there should be at least one found record for each, but I am getting nothing returned.  I just cannot wrap my head around using mongo for these basic tasks, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

I am just using nodeJS and connecting to mongoDB, there is no express or mongoose or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are mixing callback and promises for async code handling. When you call:

```
var record = db.collection('' + site_id + '_campaigns').find({name: record_name}).toArray(function(err, result) {
```

You are passing in a callback function, which will receive the resulting array of mongo records in a parameter called `result`, but then assigning the immediate returned value to a variable called 'record', which is not going to contain anything.

Here is a cleaned up version of your function.

```
function hit_the_db(db, site_id, record_name, callback) {
    // Find all records matching 'record_name'
    db.collection(site_id + 'test_campaigns').find({ name: record_name }).toArray(function(err, results) {
        // matching records are now stored in 'results'
        if (err) {
            console.log('err:', err);
        }
        return callback(err, results);
    });
}
```

Here is optional code for testing the above function.

```
// This is called to generate test data
function insert_test_records_callback(db, site_id, record_name, insert_count, callback) {
    const testRecords = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < insert_count; ++i) {
        testRecords.push({name: record_name, val: i});
    }
    db.collection(site_id + 'test_campaigns').insertMany(testRecords, function(err, result) {
        return callback(err);
    });
}

// This cleans up by deleting all test records.
function delete_test_records_callback(db, site_id, record_name, callback) {
    db.collection(site_id + 'test_campaigns').deleteMany({name: record_name}, function(err, result) {
        return callback(err);
    });
}

// Test function to insert, query, clean up test records.
function test_callback(db) {
    const site_id = 'ksdlfnsdlfu893hdsvSFJSDgfsdk';
    const test_record_name = 'test_record_callback';
    // First call the insert function
    insert_test_records_callback(db, site_id, test_record_name, 3, function(err) {
        // Once execution reaches here, insertion has completed.
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        // Do the query function
        hit_the_db(db, site_id, test_record_name, function(err, records) {
            // The query function has now completed
            console.log('hit_the_db - err:', err);
            console.log('hit_the_db - records:', records);
            delete_test_records_callback(db, site_id, test_record_name, function(err, records) {
                console.log('cleaned up test records.');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Output:

```
hit_the_db - err: null
hit_the_db - records: [ { _id: 5efe09084d078f4b7952dea8,
    name: 'test_record_callback',
    val: 0 },
  { _id: 5efe09084d078f4b7952dea9,
    name: 'test_record_callback',
    val: 1 },
  { _id: 5efe09084d078f4b7952deaa,
    name: 'test_record_callback',
    val: 2 } ]
cleaned up test records.
```

Comment: I don't understand why the first example is placed inside an `insertOne` call, that doesn't insert, does it?  Why would I have to run an `insertOne` just to retrieve a record, that just can't be right, am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't normally require it. I wanted to show a complete test with insertion and query.

Comment: When I remove the code from being inside that it doesn't work.  I need an example that fits the criteria that I specified in my question.  I do appreciate you taking the time to answer. Thanks again

Comment: I have removed the async example and made the callback example more closely resemble your original code, and added a test with multiple records.

Comment: So I am very new to mongo and nodeJS, so I just want to ask, and just so it is clear,  I really do appreciate your help with this.  Do I really need 4 functions and almost 50 lines of code to query the DB for a matching record and update it if found?  If so, I think I might just dump mongo and node altogether here.

Comment: No. I have reduced your original function from 16 lines to 9. All you need to look at is the hit_the_db function I have provided. The rest is test code. For now I will edit to reflect this. If you want I can edit to remove all of the test code, I provideded it because it is considered good practice: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I do not understand most of this, what I need to see is how I can query the database and return a matching record, everything else here is noise that makes this even harder for me to understand.  Query the database, return matching record, that is what I need

Comment: I have edited to separate out the hit_the_db function.